# Writing in a file in python executed on next run

Tags: python, file

I have the following code:

```
f=open('data.txt', 'w')
conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com')
page_html = conn.read()
data=BeautifulSoup(page_html)
count=0
out=""
for val in data.findAll('td'):
    count=count+1
    if(count%2==0 and val.contents):
        out=out+val.contents[0].strip(' \n\t')+"\n"
    if(count>=18):
        f.write(out+"\n")
        break
f.closed
```

Now when I execute the code, the output of the previous run goes in the file data.txt

For eg, now I have example.com in the url, I run the code then I change the url to stackoverflow.com. Now when I run it again and check data.txt I have the output of example.com in the data.txt file. The next time I run with a different url I am getting output of stackoverflow.com in the file. Can somebody help me out with this? I checked the outputs at every stage in the code. If I directly give the output instead of writing in file, it works perfectly.

Comment: Don't you want `f.close()` at the end, instead of `f.closed`?

Comment: It should also be pointed out that you don't use parenthesis around if statements in Python. It should be `if count >= 18:` and `if count % 2 == 0 and val.contents:`

Comment: @burhan Would that make a difference? It doesn't generate any error or warning.

Comment: @gopi1410 its the right way of doing things in Python. It works as a side effect of what ( ) mean in Python; it is not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use `f.close()` instead of `f.closed`. The latter doesn't close the file. It returns a boolean that tells you whether or not the file has been closed.

I'd also suggest that you use a [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) instead of closing the file manually.

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    # etc...
```

Comment: +1. [The `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is the best solution for [opening files](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement). It's not only more pythonic and readable but handles closing for you, even when exceptions occur.

Comment: how is f.close() different from f.closed? I thought both do the same thing.

Comment: @gopi1410 ``f.close()`` is a function that closes the file. ``f.closed`` is an attribute that tells you if the file is closed. You should probably read the docs more closely - it's very rare in Python that there are two ways to do one thing (it's a specific design aim that there is not).

Comment: & thanks for the `with` statement. Didn't know about it, Haven't used python much.

Comment: @Lattyware @Mark Byers Changing `f.closed` to `f.close()` didn't work too! Haven't tried the with statement though. I thought it should have worked after f.close() as file was closing properly. I dont get it why it is saving the previous output each time in the file.

Comment: @Lattyware Also can I write in the file with the use of `with` statement? All the examples & documentation that I googled out now only show how to read files using `with` statement.

Comment: @gopi1410 Yes, just pass ``open()`` the appropriate flag, just as you would normally.

Comment: What does "BeautifulSoup" do? When you run your code for the first time, what is in 'data.txt'? Is there more code here than you're showing (i.e. other than import urllib2)?

Answer (score 1):

You want to close your file with the

```
 f.close()
```

function call and thereby flush your output buffers.